# Repeating Escherized tile tessellation using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I have a tessellation tile in geometry nodes that I would like to repeat using geometry nodes while using 3 to 4 different colors.

**Single Tile:**

[image: img1]

**Trying to get:**

[image: img2]

**What I have:**

[image: img3]

I can duplicate and rotate and move it into position but if I wave 20 rows and columns that gets a little tedious.  Is there a way to "**automate**" the process to say get 10 rows and 8 columns or 20 tiles by just typing in the number?

**PS: I plan on trying / adding multiple tilings like this so the rotations may not be the same.

Example:**

[image: imgg]

Attached File below:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you forgot the yellow one...

[image]

Then you just have to instance it to a grid and rotate the instances a bit...

**EDIT:** As you want to reuse this the first thing you'll have to do is find the center of rotation. I modified a bit the .Blend in this purpose. If You have 3 motifs you'll have to change the rotation of the motifs (to 120 and -120 of course).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! How did you calculate what the center should be?

Comment: The center point is where you have the 4 motifs intersect, I will add a switch to the a new .blend so you can experiment by yourself.